# Various read-line methods failing on Android

Tags: android, file, readline

OK, I'm officially frustrated with file handling on the Android. I'm new to it (only a few days) so I might just be missing something obvious. I have successfully written a short file of multiple lines with CSV data on each line. That's not the problem; reading is. I started with this (leaving out the exception handling and parsing for clarity):

```
        FileInputStream in = context.openFileInput("foo.txt");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader( in );
        BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader( isr );
        String inline;
        while( (inline = buffreader.readLine())!=null)
        {
            // parse CSV here
        }
```

I got an immediate null when reading the line. So I worked back up the line and tried reading raw bytes using various examples in SO as a pattern. I won't reproduce all the fails, but things like this didn't work either:

```
        FileInputStream in = context.openFileInput("foo.txt");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader( in );
        BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader( isr );
        CharBuffer buff = CharBuffer.allocate(1024);
        isr.read(buff);
        String s = buff.toString();
```

Debugging showed that the character buffer and string had consumed characters, but they were blank. Well, I can truly go old-school (I programmed in C before it was a decade old) if necessary. The following worked:

```
        FileInputStream in = context.openFileInput("foo.txt");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader( in );
        int c;
        String foo = ""; 
        while( (c = isr.read())>=0)
            foo += (char)c;
```

"foo" managed to have the whole contents which I can split up and process, but I dislike that it's so coarse. Yes, it works, but I'd like to know why the others didn't. I tried to stick closely to the various examples in SO, but had no success.

Any ideas about what might be wrong with the first attempts?

Comment: Please provide foo.txt file

Comment: For me the code you provide (the first one, didn't look the other ones) is correct. Perhaps the problem is simply you don't open the file ? Where is the file located ? In the asset folder ?

Comment: Yeah..openFileInput is for Internal storage(Application package).so I am sure your file is not present there.

Answer (score 0):

```
          do {
              inline=bruffreader.readLine();
              if(inline != null) {
                 //parse here
              }
          } while (inline != null);
```

worked for me, it didn't return null